# Recruiting y sus fallidas traducciones

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Ésta es una de las palabras más complicadas de traducir que he encontrado. La mayoría de los diccionarios traducen este término por "reclutamiento" cuando el término es mucho más amplio y casi nunca se utiliza en este caso.

Muchas veces he pensado que debería ser traducido por "empleo", pero no siempre es lo más adecuado.

¿Hay alguna palabra equivalente en español?

Comment: A mí reclutar y reclutamiento me suenan bien, aunque lo asocio levemente al servicio militar. Nótese, de todas formas, que tanto en inglés como en castellano la palabra viene del francés *recruter*, la cual a su vez viene del latín.

Comment: @fedorqui en inglés también tiene una connotación (yo diría fuerte) con el servicio militar (en EE. UU. al menos), a menos que vaya con algún modificador como «corporate recruiter» o «recruiter for ___».

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con fedorqui y creo que Mg Gm debería elaborar un poco más acerca de cuáles son las otras acepciones o significados de "recruiting" (posiblemente con ejemplos) para poder entender mejor porqué "reclutamiento" no es suficiente. Yo ofrecería **"colocación"** como en "agencia de colocación de empleo", pero no sé si diría que un _recruiter_ es un "colocador". Para poder ofrecer una respuesta más completa que eso, necesitaría entender cómo Mg Gm va user el termino y/o cuáles son las otras acepciones que tiene en inglés.

Comment: @guifa I think in the UK we use it primarily for recruiting workers for a job although the military do have recruitment centres.

Comment: @mdewey The same applies in my country, so I don't why is considered a bad translation.

Comment: Aparte de que la palabra *reclutar* y sus derivados me parece perfectamente utilizable en este ámbito, en España se ha venido usando *selección de personal* desde hace tiempo.

Answer (score 8):

***Reclutamiento*** según la RAE es `Reunir gente para un propósito determinado.`

Para el tema de los empleos es una palabra muy común. Consulte con amigos que trabajan en el área de recursos humanos y es la palabra que usan. Si haces una búsqueda en google de "reclutar talentos" vas a ver que todos los resultados tienen que ver con RRHH.

Como ejercicio busqué la palabra "reclutar" en google-imagenes y no hay ni una sola imagen que tenga que ver con reclutamiento militar. Todos los resultados tiene que ver con reclutar empleados o reclutar voluntarios para diferentes tareas.

Teniendo en cuenta la definición de la RAE, lo que dice fedorqui que el origen de la palabra en inglés y español es el mismo del francés y que la comunidad de RRHH la usa, creo que la traducción de `Recruiting` es `Reclutamiento`.

Comment: A lo mejor es que los que trabajan en RRHH hablan en [argot (2)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3XeSg6P), pero no es el lenguaje de los legos en la materia. Nunca he oído a nadie usar este verbo o sus derivados (por muy lícito que sea según una acepción del DLE) con este significado (no tengo amigos en RRHH).

Answer (score 3):

Preguntas si hay una palabra para usarla como traducción de *recruiting*. La correspondencia exacta entre palabras es rara: no suele haber muchas palabras que puedan usarse en dos idiomas con una correspondencia que resulte natural en todo tipo de contextos. Hay que hacer suposiciones razonables de cómo habría dicho eso en español esa persona (en realidad, una persona ficticia).

Se me ocurren varios casos:

- Si el que habla es un profesional de RRHH, y parece que ellos utilizan el "reclutar", pues así habría que decirlo.
- Si no es así, el "reclutar" me suena raro. Yo mismo, aunque no soy de RRHH, participo en mi empresa en el **proceso de selección** (y así lo suelo decir). También digo **selección de personal**.
- Si el que habla no está en el lado de los "reclutadores" sino en el de los "reclutados", lo más probable es que diga que va a una **entrevista de trabajo** más que a un "reclutamiento".
- Y si hablamos de las empresas de **colocación**, yo diría que el matiz está en que, en vez de tener un puesto y buscar a una persona para cubrirlo, tenemos una persona y buscamos algún empleo en el que sea aceptado (de ahí el hecho de usar el verbo "colocar").

Y ahora, permitidme hacer una reflexión. Antes eran "los de Personal" y ahora son "los de Recursos Humanos". Al final es el mismo departamento, pero me causa recelo el que se quitaran del nombre que trataban con "personas" y decidieran considerarlos "recursos".

Comment: y cada vez tienden más a ser _los de recursos_, prescindiendo de lo de _humanos_.

Comment: Respecto a la última reflexión, es posible que varíe con la empresa, ya que una de las últimas en las que estuve (que por cierto era muy grande) tenía un jefe de recursos humanos y un jefe de personal, estando el segundo en un rango por encima del primero.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que tienden a verlo como si fuese un término militar en todo aspecto. No es así.

En Chile, al menos, se usa mucho en todo ámbito de lo que respecte a la búsqueda de trabajo.

> — Proceso de *reclutamiento* para trabajar de empaque/enfermera/junior/vendedor/reponedor.

Que los traductores no lo adopten porque suena *mal*, en verdad no es una excusa, porque perfectamente se puede usar como *reclutamiento*.

Comment: Si bien es usado en el ambito militar, tambien es perfectamente aplicable al ámbito laboral. De acuerdo 100%, Ustanak